Carrito de compras con JavaScript
Hola buenas tardes estuve haciendo un carrito de compras con JavaScript y al momento de colocar los productos en el archivo JSON utilice una promesa fetch que la misma no funciona dado que luego de ejecutar la pagina los productos no son mostrados si el archivo HTML es ejecutado con Live server si muestra los mismos pero desde el explorador de archivos no sucede esto
const contenedorCard = document.querySelector("#contenedor-productos");


fetch("./Js/productos.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        productos = data;
        crearCardInicio(productos);
    })


function crearCardInicio (productos){
    productos.forEach(producto => {
        const nuevoProducto = document.createElement("div");
        nuevoProducto.classList = "card-producto";
        nuevoProducto.innerHTML = `
            <img src=${producto.img} alt=${producto.nombre}>
            <h3 class="producto-nombre">${producto.nombre}</h3>
            <p class="producto-precio">$${producto.precio}</p>
            <button class="producto-agregar">Agregar</button>
        `
        contenedorCard.appendChild(nuevoProducto);
        nuevoProducto.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
        .addEventListener("click", () => agregarAlCarrito (producto))
    });
}

